# How to upsert two fields?

Tags: php, mongodb

How can I upsert (update if not added) two fields at the same time?
It worked for a single field, but it doesn't work for two anymore.

Am I doing something wrong?:

```
$db->url->update(   
      array("url" => $linkurlcache),
      array('$set' => array('url' => $linkurlcache, 'pos' => $rand_num)),
      array("upsert" => true),
      array("multi" => true)
);
```

Comment: when you say it doesn't work - do you get an error? or do you get unexpected insert/update result?

Comment: thanks for the interest, but I found what was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really hate having to answer my own question. I would have deleted it but I couldn't find a solution on any website.

Anyhow, the `array("multi" => true)` made a lot of sense considering we are calling the update function, but it's wrong.

The correct solution is without it!
Just:

```
$db->url->update(   
      array("field1" => $field1),
      array('$set' => array('field1' => $field1, 'field2' => $field2)),
      array("upsert" => true)
);
```

Because `upsert` actually makes an insert (if the query doesn't match).

Comment: You may wish to add field2 to the find criteria too by the sounds of your question so as to make sure you only insert both fields if they both are the value